# Opening circuit breaker based on the response status with NodeJs (Opossum)

Tags: node.js, nestjs, circuit-breaker

I am using [opossum](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opossum) to implement `circuit breaker` for my `nodeJs` application.
Currently whenever there is an error, either it's `Bad Request` or `Bad Gateway`, the `circuit breaker` is opened and blocked the next calls.

Is there a way to implement to open `circuit breaker` only for some response status like `HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR` and so on.

The following is my current code.

```
       const response = this.circuitBreakers
            .fire(...args)
            .catch((result) => {
                console.log(`in circuit : ${result}`);
                this.logger.error(result?.response);
            });
```

Right now, the only way I found is to close the circuit breaker immediately after it's open if it's returning other statuses like following

```
const response = this.circuitBreakers
                .fire(...args)
                .catch((result) => {
                    if (parseInt(result.response.status != 500) {
                        this.circuitBreaker.close();
                    } else {
                        console.log(`in circuit : ${result}`);
                        this.logger.error(result?.response);
                    }
                });
```

**Solution**

Thanks to `Charchit Kapoor`'s answer, here is the solution I added in my `Circuit Breaker` 's `option`

```
const options: CircuitOptions = {
  errorFilter: (err) => {
    const status = parseInt(err.response.status, 10);
    // I want the circuit breaker to open only when the error status is 500
    if (status != 500) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  },
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `errorFilter` config function, which is a part of the `options` object, passed in the constructor for `CircuitBreaker`.

[Link to documentation of `errorFilter`.](https://nodeshift.dev/opossum/#circuitbreaker)